# Using loc and map to change values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have two DataFrames, that have same column names, and each row has unique Import_ID. I want to import the missing values in 2 columns from df1 to df2 based on the same Import_ID.

I already did this for one column and it works fine, but I want to do it for 2 columns at the same time.
For one column I wrote :

```
df2.loc[(numpy.isnan(df2['DeliveryNoteNo']))& (~numpy.isnan(df1['DeliveryNoteNo'])), 'DeliveryNoteNo'] = df2['Import_ID'].map(df1.set_index('Import_ID')['DeliveryNoteNo'])
```

And this works fine, so I wanted to do same for 2 columns, so that every time I do an update do df2 it also gives the date when it was updated.

I tried this, but it only returns me an error :" TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable"

```
df2.loc[(numpy.isnan(df2.InvoiceNo))& (~numpy.isnan(df1['InvoiceNo'])), ['InvoiceNo','Modified_Date']] = df2['Import_ID'].map(df1.set_index('Import_ID')[['InvoiceNo', 'Modified_Date']])
```

For example : 
df1 :

```
     InvoiceNo     OrderNo  DeliveryNoteNo     Modified_Date   Import_ID
0   950094591.0  7027514279    1.000000e+00  23-08-2019 14:30  7027514279_100
1   950094591.0  7027514279    2.000000e+00  23-08-2019 14:30  7027514279_100.1
2                7027514279                  23-08-2019 14:30  7027514279_100.2
```

df2:

```
     InvoiceNo     OrderNo  DeliveryNoteNo     Modified_Date   Import_ID
0                7027514279    1.000000e+00  21-08-2019 14:30  7027514279_100
1   950094591.0  7027514279                  21-08-2019 14:30  7027514279_100.1
2                7027514279                  21-08-2019 14:30  7027514279_100.2
```

df2 should later look like this:

```
     InvoiceNo     OrderNo  DeliveryNoteNo     Modified_Date   Import_ID
0   950094591.0  7027514279    1.000000e+00  23-08-2019 14:30  7027514279_100
1   950094591.0  7027514279    2.000000e+00  23-08-2019 14:30  7027514279_100.1
2                7027514279                  21-08-2019 14:30  7027514279_100.2
```

Comment: have you tried something with merge?

Comment: Yes, I tried with merge and it only showed me df1 rows, and none of the df2 that were different from df1

Comment: there's no `importID` on your sample dataframes, correct? or is it just the index? if that's the case then use `df2.combine_first(df1)`

Comment: I forgot to add it to the example, there are over 20 different columns, and since I was working on these 4 I forgot to add it,..I updated my question now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df2.set_index('Import_ID').combine_first(df1.set_index('Import_ID')).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
        InvoiceNo     OrderNo  DeliveryNoteNo     Modified_Date
0     950094591.0  7027514279             1.0  21-08-2019 14:30
1     950094591.0  7027514279             2.0  21-08-2019 14:30
2             NaN  7027514279             NaN  21-08-2019 14:30
```

Comment: that means that it will alway update everything, even if the InvoiceNo and DeliveryNoteNo columns are not updated... I can't use it like that, I need it specifically to be for those three columns only. That means that the Column Modified_Date will only take the new date when the InvoiceNo or DeliveryNoteNo are imported, otherwise it remains same, even if at the df1 it got a new Modified_date. Hope I explained well

Comment: that's almost correct. The result from this operation is not modifying `df2` inplace, so you can take the result from this dataframe and take only the columns you need, agree?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Non-Exhaustive Mapping by `map` with `fillna` combined?

Basically, you need to create two dictionaries first, based on the column values from your `df1` to place the values you want to update in your 2 columns in `df2`:

```
dictionary_1 = dict(zip(df1['Import_ID'], df1['DeliveryNoteNo']))
dictionary_2 = dict(zip(df1['Import_ID'], df1['InvoiceNo']))
```

Then, you use these dictionaries to update `df2` but using `fillna` with parameters equal to the original value in `df2` column if it returns `False`:

```
df2['DeliveryNoteNo'] = df2['Import_ID'].map(dictionary_1).fillna(df2['DeliveryNoteNo'])
```

Do the same for the second column to update:

```
df2['InvoiceNo'] = df2['Import_ID'].map(dictionary_1).fillna(df2['InvoiceNo'])
```

The `fillna` parameter will not give a `Nan` value to your column if the `map` returns `False`, which means, it won't update any existing value that does not have the same id as in keys in both of your dictionaries.

Hope this helps :)).

Comment: that is what I would like to avoid, I thought there is an option that is similar to my current code to do it. but thanks for the answer